# Allow safe.duckduckgo.com but block duckduckgo.com on Mac (potentially in the hosts file)?

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra, duckduckgo

I want to completely disallow `duckduckgo.com` on my computer and only allow `safe.duckduckgo.com` to be reachable in any browser (on macOS High Sierra).

My initial thought was to somehow specify that in the `hosts file` (can be opened using `sudo nano /etc/hosts`). However, if I add duckduckgo.com (using `127.0.0.1   duckduckgo.com`), then I can't reach safe.duckduckgo.com either.

A different example would be to block `google.com` but still allow `scholar.google.com`.

How can I do that?

(Or is there perhaps a better way than doing it via the hosts file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

safe.duckduckgo.com is a CNAME for duckduckgo.com, so when you look up safe… it turns around and looks up the blocked one.

To address that, you'll need to provide hard-coded IP addresses for safe.duckduckgo.com. For example, the following should work as you expect:

```
127.0.0.1   duckduckgo.com
107.20.240.232  safe.duckduckgo.com
```

You can get the addresses this way:

```
$ host safe.duckduckgo.com
safe.duckduckgo.com is an alias for duckduckgo.com.
duckduckgo.com has address 107.20.240.232
duckduckgo.com has address 23.21.193.169
duckduckgo.com has address 184.72.104.138
duckduckgo.com mail is handled by 10 in1-smtp.messagingengine.com.
duckduckgo.com mail is handled by 20 in2-smtp.messagingengine.com.
```